# How to implement Scroll Navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm not sure if the name "scroll bar" is true at all. I would like to install a scrollbar, in which you can simply select a city with the mouse wheel (on a smartphone with a wipe) and then select the possible cities of the respective country in the second window.
I mean something like this has already been seen but unfortunately I could not find a good example.

[image: Scrollbar]

Does anyone know the exact name and has perhaps a sample code?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok. You have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated the answer as per comment**

I think you better use **[Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation)** for this.

You can find all the details and support you need in its **[Basic Usage](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)** page.

**And about your Question** - only post question if you have tried solving it by your self *(if you have tried, post the method you have tried with a sample code)* or try **Googling** it, this may help more than you know.

**Update2**

As per your comment, i understand that what you need is a spinner in this case you can use [**Input Spinner Plugin**](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Select-Based-Input-Spinner-Plugin-For-jQuery-Select-Step.html) for this. You will need some styling changes but this will work your way.
Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. It's about a roll bar. No menu structure that opens in an extra window but rather as a role on which the whole cities are applied. Which should only be rotated in the small window.

Comment: @Syntax6 Sorry I only know English and our native languages. So please ask in English.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. It's about a roll bar. No menu structure that opens in an extra window but rather as a role on which the whole cities are applied. Which should only be rotated in the small window.

Comment: @Syntax6 so what you want is a **spinner** with states name on it.?

Comment: A spinner. Yes.

Comment: @Syntax6 I have **updated my answer** for you, please do check it. If it was helpful please do mark it as the answer. :)